# How to fetch the merchant id by giving the customer id by using function?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have table called "CUSTOMER BASIC INFO".
which are having customer id and merchant id.
now I want write a function for fetching merchant id by giving customer id as input parameter.
so please answer me detail;

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMerchantId @cid dataTypeOfCustomerId(length)
AS
SELECT merchant_id FROM CUSTOMER_BASIC_INFO WHERE customer_id = @cid
GO;
```

Call it as

```
EXEC GetMerchantId @cid = '5';
```

Comment: PL/SQL (as tagged) is procedural extension to Oracle's SQL. Your code is not Oracle. Just saying; maybe Kishore wrongly tagged the question, can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

Code is kind of simple:

```
create or replace function f_test (par_customer_id in customer_basic_info.customer_id%type)
  return customer_basic_info.merchant_id%type
is
  retval customer_basic_info.merchant_id%type;
begin
  select merchant_id
  into retval
  from customer_basic_info
  where customer_id = par_customer_id;

  return retval;
end;
/
```

However, this will return `TOO_MANY_ROWS` error of customer has more than a single merchant (which is quite possible), so - what would you want to return in such a case? Any merchant? No merchant? Let function raise an error? Raise it, but you'll handle it somehow?